# Replacing functionality of one button with the functionality of another button using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, limesurvey

I am using LimeSurvey and I have to change the functionality of a button using javascript.

I have a button with ID "NextButton", and On clicking that I want to call "SubmitButton" and hence the functionality of "SubmitButton" is executed.

I can only do this using Javascript/Jquery a nothing can be done in HTML.

Please let me know if it is possible.

I know it has to do something with OnClick event, but I am not sure how to replace the functionalities like I said.

Comment: May be like this: `$(NextButton).click(function(e){ $(SubmitButton).trigger("click"); e.stopPropagation(); });`

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible with mere HTML because you cannot process logic with HTML.

The most easy thing you can do is simulating the click on another button using JQuery:

Given the following buttons:

```
<input type="button" id="action_1" value="Button A" />
<input type="button" id="action_2" value="Button B" />
```

You can use something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#action_1").on("click", function() { 
        $("#action_2").trigger("click");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#NextButton').click(function(event) {
        $('#movenextbtn, #movesubmitbtn').click();
    });         
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have `jQuery` available:

```
$(function() {
  // grab NextButton and replace its click event
  $('#NextButton').click(function() {
    $('#SubmitButton').click();
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you **have** jQuery loaded in your page? Did you see any error in the javascript console?

Answer (score 0):

another method

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id = "del-btn">Old btn</button>
<div id = "sho-btn"></div>


 <script>
    var a = "<button onclick="function();" class='btn btn-primary'>New Button</button>";
    document.getElementById("del-btn").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById("sho-btn").innerHTML = a;
    </script>
```